# How to write string to file within broadcast receiver ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have set up a Broadcast Receiver to capture  current running task. The Class display the task name using Toast but I need to write the String to a file

Is there a way I can write the String to a file within the Broadcast Receiver?

```
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {
    try {

        //TextView  run = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        //ArrayList<String> task1 = new ArrayList<String>();

         ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext
                 .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am
                  .getRunningTasks(1);
          for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {
              task=aTask.baseActivity.getPackageName();
              //task1.add(task);
             // run.setText(task);

            Toast.makeText(aContext, task , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              saveTask(aContext,task);
          }
```

Now I want to write the  string task into a file. How to do it within broadcast receiver class?

Comment: capture current turnning task meance ? what u want to capture?

Comment: What is the problem. You can simply write any string to files as long as you got what you want to write. [This Storage Article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) explains all possible ways.

Comment: Cant u add the code to create a file and write the string to it subsequently to the code for ur toast?

Comment: capturing package name of the current task

Comment: @bhavithra, did you try my answer ?

Comment: i need to write within Broadcastreceiver class.i already tried this .it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Following is a simple code to write a text in file.

```
File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
myFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
myOutWriter.append( "Your Text goes here");
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
```

Also you need to define following permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @Bhavithra, this is my answer.

Comment: oh sry i didnt notice . bt it wont work within broadcast recevier class @Kedarnath

Comment: @bhavithra, why, whats the reason ?

Comment: i dont knw,i put my own solution  bt it write file in /data  directory

Comment: i couldnt access the /data how to write file in SD card